Incorrect property type after spreading an object from union
Let's assume I have a type that represents a union of objects:
type ExampleType = {
    type: "number",
    data: 0
} | {
    type: "string",
    data: "",
}

And when I spreading an object of this type, I'm no longer able to discriminate over the union, looks like the variables that comes from spread operator are no longer connected:
const example = (param: ExampleType) => {
    const {type, ...data} = param;

    if (type === 'number') {
        const result = data;
    }
}

In this example result has a union type, but without spreading it works as expected:
    if (param.type === "number") {
        const result1 = param.data
    }

Here result1 gets {data: 0} type, as I wanted.
Full demo
Is it possible to disciminate over unions of object using spread operator? If yes, how can I do this?
I've tried many variants of typing the unions, butgot the same result.

This is a missing feature of TS, requested at ms/TS#46680. See the linked q/a above for more info
